# FirstDayofWeek and LastDayOfWeek on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I got a strange result from my first day of week and last day of week on my script, so I have a FirstDayOfWeek (Start Monday) and LastDayOfWeek (End Sunday), but It got strange a bit when the date start on Sunday it refer to the next Week.

For example:

- date = '2021-09-05' (Sunday)
- FirstDayOfWeek = '2021-09-06' (Monday)
- LastDayOfWeek = '2021-09-12' (Sunday)

What I expected:

- date = '2021-09-05' (Sunday)
- FirstDayOfWeek = '2021-08-30' (Monday)
- LastDayOfWeek = '2021-09-05' (Sunday) < Same as date

This is my Query:

```sql
declare @date_start datetime
set @date_start = '2021-09-05'

SELECT CAST(DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, @date_start))+2, @date_start) AS DATE) as FirstDayOfWeek, 
       CAST(DATEADD(dd, 8-(DATEPART(dw, @date_start)), @date_start) AS DATE) as LastDayOfWeek
```

Comment: Use a calendar table. Unless you're American SQL Server makes some very odd decisions about when your weeks start and end.

Comment: [Article about calendar tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/); also see [`SET DATEFIRST` in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql) if you expect things like `dw` to behave a certain way. And please spell out `DAY` and `WEEKDAY`! See [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) for more info.

Comment: Woww, thank you so much, it such a miracle, I do the `SET DATEFIRST 1` and edit my query. Thank you again, it solved now

Comment: Tip: `( @@DateFirst + DatePart( weekday, YourDate ) - 1 ) % 7 + 1` will always return an integer from `1` to `7` with `1` corresponding to Sunday regardless of the setting of `DateFirst` or `Language`. You can tweak it to move the starting day.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this code! And of course, you can set a different date, the results will be as expected.

```
declare @date_start datetime
set @date_start = '2021-09-05'

SELECT DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, @date_start - 1), 0) AS FirstDayOfWeek,
       DATEADD(day, 6, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, @date_start - 1), 0)) AS LastDayOfWeek;
```

---

Thanks,